# How to start a c# empty project in Visual Studio.

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have just started to learn c# and want to do some starter worksheets, but I cant even figure out how to create an empty project for c# in Visual studio. I know this is a stupid question but I just can not figure it out. If anyone can help me out, it would be appreciated.

Comment: file -> new -> project -> console app

Comment: Did you search? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zfzh36t7.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: What kind of project? Are you writing a desktop application? Command line program? Web site? Library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although a project must reside in a solution, you can create a solution that has no projects.

To create an empty solution
in the File menu, click `New` and then click `New Project`.

In the left pane, select `Installed`, select `Other Project Types`, and then select `Visual Studio Solutions` from the expanded list.

In the middle pane, select `Blank Solution`.

Set the Name and Location values for your solution, then click `OK`.

See the [Visual Studio documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/creating-solutions-and-projects) for further guidance.

Comment: There is also a search field when creating a new Project. If you type in "Blank" "Solution" or some combination of that, you'll also be presented with a Blank Solution option. There is also a Blank Project that can be added to a Solution.